# Mockito thenReturn always null , Spring-Boot + Junit5 + Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

I'm trying to implement Mockito to test a particular method but the `.thenReturn(...)` seems to always be returning a `null` object instead of what I intended:

I am using mockito 2.22.0 and Junit-5 and spring-boot 2.0.4.RELEASE

User resultUser=userService.save(userDto);
The above line return always nullpointer exception.not sure why
resultUser always retuning null,

### My Test class

```
 @SpringBootTest
    public class UserServiceTests {
    
    @InjectMocks
    private UserService userService =new UserServiceImpl();
    
    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Mock
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception{
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        
    }
    
    @DisplayName("Test saveRegistrationTest method making call to Repository")
    @Test
    public void saveRegistrationTest() {
        
        User user =new User();
        user.setFirstName("TestFN");
        user.setLastName("TestLN");
        user.setEmail("test@test.com");
        user.setPassword("7asdf7asdfi");
        
        User testUser =new User();
        testUser.setFirstName("TestFN");
        
        UserRegistrationDto userDto = new UserRegistrationDto();
        userDto.setFirstName("TestFN");
        
        when(userRepository.save(testUser )).thenReturn(user);
        
        **User resultUser=userService.save(userDto);**
        
        String firstName=(userService.save(userDto)).getFirstName();
        String lastName=(userService.save(userDto)).getLastName();
        String resultEmailFromRepo=(userService.save(userDto)).getEmail();
        String password=(userService.save(userDto)).getPassword();
        
        assertNotNull(user);
        assertEquals("TestLN", firstName);
        assertEquals("TestLN", lastName);
        assertEquals("test@test.com", resultEmailFromRepo);
        assertNotNull(password);
        assertEquals("7asdf7asdfi", password);
    }
```

### User Entity

```
 @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Todo> todoList = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Collection<Role> roles;
```

### UserDTO

```
public class UserRegistrationDto {

    @NotEmpty
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty
    private String lastName;

    @NotEmpty
    private String password;

    @NotEmpty
    private String confirmPassword;

    @Email
    @NotEmpty
    private String email;

    @Email
    @NotEmpty
    private String confirmEmail;

    @AssertTrue
    private Boolean terms;
```

### Userserviceimpl class

```
   public User save(UserRegistrationDto registration){
        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName(registration.getFirstName());
        user.setLastName(registration.getLastName());
        user.setEmail(registration.getEmail());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(registration.getPassword()));
        user.setRoles(Arrays.asList(new Role("TEST_USER")));
        user.setTodoList(null);
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

Comment: Don’t know if it will solve your problem but a member variable with InjectMocks should not be initialised. Moreover, the before each method shouldn’t be necessary when SpringBootTest is present.

Answer (score 5):

#### Don't

```java
@InjectMocks
private UserService userService = new UserServiceImpl();
```

This "object" is never managed by spring!

---

#### Best

```java
@SpringBootTest
class UserServiceTest {
  @Autowired
  private UserService testee;

  @MockBean
  private UserRepository userRepoMock; // done!
  // ... many test methods, like: when(userRepoMock.xxx).thenYYY
  // testee.someMethod()
  // verify(userRepoMock...)
  // ...
}
```

where the service looks like:

```java
@Service // or some other "spring managed bean"
public class UserService {
  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;
 ...
}
```

---

And as johannes commented:

```
@BeforeEach
```

is *not needed* (but not harmful??!) in this setup.

---

#### Core Problem

When we use a concrete object instance as "argument matcher" for mockito:

```java
when(userRepository.save(someObject)).thenReturn(someMock);
```

, we should ensure, that when (during test):

```java
userRepository(someOtherObject)
```

..is called,

```
someObject.equals(someOtherObject)
```

... is `true`!("Equality Matcher")

Otherwise mockito can'/won't match that invocation.

We can resolve by, implementing (custom) `equals` (and `hashCode`) methods:

```java
// e.g. with lombok:
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
// ...
class UserRegistrationDto {
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
  String name;
}
```

[`EqualsAndHashCode`](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode)(Recommended, but do it well! (lombok small print, or manual!))

---

Or by using a "wider Argument Matcher", like:

```java
when(userRepository.save(any(UserRegistrationDto.class)).thenReturn(myMockResponse);
```

..or even:

```java
when(userRepository.save(any(/*java.lang.Object*/))...
```

[`ArgumentMatchers` javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html)

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
   <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.22.0</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

no any() method found

Comment: I have udpated my question with more information , Please have look

Comment: the best approach nto working for me. so i went to injectmocks

Comment: no any method found in import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers 
with mockito 2.22.0 
If i use latest version 4.2.0 , my test not working ,

Comment: if i use your best suggested approach , i used to get nullpointer exception , so i went back to my old approach

Comment: injectmocks is ok, but `new UserServiceImpl()` is a "killer" in terms of spring: `new UserServiceImpl()` is not a "spring bean"!

Comment: if you get a null-pointer on my (proposed) "best approach", then something is odd with your spring configuration.

Comment: can i give my git link ?

Comment: sure! you could have posted upfront :)

Comment: https://github.com/tamilsri02/todo-app

Comment: a nightmare!^^^

Comment: (why) it must be spring-boot:2.0.4 ??

Comment: which one i can use than  ? latest version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240585/discussion-between-prabagaran-sellamuthu-and-xerx593).

Comment: Thanks its worked finally!
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications

Comment: I'd like to point out that there is no need to bring the Spring context here if it is a pure unit test. I'd advise removing `@SpringBootTest` and opting for `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` instead.